# How to use a 3rd party JavaScript library in my Laravel 5.5 project?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm building a project with Laravel 5.5, and I'm struggling to pull in [Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix).

So far I've run the following:

```
npm i eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker
npm install
```

Added the following to **`resources\assets\js\app.js`**:

```
require('../../../node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js')
```

Added the following to **`webpack.mix.js`**:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles('node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css', 'public/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css');
```

I have the following in my **view**:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

And finally I compiled everything with:

```
npm run dev
```

This works and allows me to use the datetimepicker, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

**How can I use the bootstrap-datetimepicker library in my project correctly and cleanly?**

Comment: In **app.js**, you can use a bit shorter version `require('./eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker')`

Comment: just add the files needed for  bootstrap-datetimepicker in your public folder.. and include the link in your view, nothing more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow @ljubadr method just `require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');`

If you don't know which name you should require, you can go to the package that you have download in this case should be `node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/` find `package.json` and use the `name` value in `package.json`.

also please do double confirm the package do support webpack or not, some package does not support webpack then you would need to use import loader to load the library instead.

Comment: Great! Do I still need to pull in the styles from the `node_modules` folder in **webpack.mix.js**?

Comment: Yep just checked and I do.